# Eevee renderer looks bad when rendering big objects on long distances

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Render and preview are showing somehow "glitched" object edges. End clip distance is set to high enough value for object to be fully visible.

(this is rendered at 4km distance - I wanted to remain at scale and I hoped that won't be an issue...)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's seems there are some problems with objects at distance if ratio between clip start and clip end is to big. Increasing clip start from 0.01m to 1m (both in camera and viewport settings) fixed the issue. I don't know if this is some sort of rounding error, but I hope this answer helps someone else...

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's because of Z depth buffer I think. lower the depth delta, higher the Z fight.